Don't understand async await execution order
async function funcTwo() {
  return new Promise((r) => r());
}

async function funcOne() {
  console.log("A");

  (async () => {
    await funcTwo();
    console.log("B");
  })();
  console.log("C");
}

await funcOne();

console.log("Done");

According to my knowledge the output should be as follows:
A
C
B 
Done

My reasoning is:
1.funcOne runs
2.A is printed
3.async function runs and promise is resolved immediately thus console.log("B") is moved to the mircotask queue
4.C is printed
5.funcOne is resolved and console.log("Done"); is moved to the mircotask queue.
6.Tasks are fetched from the queue and B and Done are printed in that order. (console.log("B") is added to the queue before console.log("done"))
However the output is:
A
C
Done
B

B and Done are switched
Can someone explain what I got wrong?

The async function that prints B is not awaited for so it will print B when it eventually gets resolved but Done is part of the main execution order. At least that's what I think is happening

I'm not a JS expert, but can guess that it has to do with "double async-ness" (explicitly returning Promise from async function) - does the output match your expectations if only one Promise is retained? That might affect the specific tick when the outer promise is resolved.

@STerliakov. Although still unsure, I think you may be right. If I return a simple value say 5, the output is what I expected. Returning a promise from an async does not resolve immediately hence my step 3 is wrong.

You're not  awaiting the immediately-invoked asynchronous function. This waits for something, and then will log "B" some time later. There is no guarantee when this will happen in relation to the other "C" and "Done" statements.

If you have an async function that executes a return with a promise object, then the promise that the function returns will be pending, never settled. The promise returned by the async function will be locked-in to the promise given to the return statement.
Let's give the involved promises some names. This is essentially the same script, but with variable names for all relevant promises:
async function f2() {
    const p0 = Promise.resolve();
    return p0;
}

async function f1() {
    console.log("A");

    async function f3() {
        const p2 = f2();
        await p2;
        console.log("B");
    }
    
    const p3 = f3();
    console.log("C");
}

const p1 = f1();
const p4 = await p1;
console.log("Done");

Even though p0 is a fulfilled promise, p2 is not. p2 is locked-in to p0, and internally a then is attached to p0 to listen for its fulfillment, so that p2 can follow that same state transition, and be fulfilled too. But such (hidden) then callback needs a promise job to be put in the queue (microtask queue). As a consequence, p0 will not fulfill synchronously, but later.
On the other hand, funcOne returns a fulfilled promise, as there is no await it executes itself. Note that the await in the nested anonymous function only pauses that anonymous function, not funcOne. The latter will continue to log "B" without considering the state of any promise, and so it returns undefined as the value of a fulfilled promise.
If you make your reasoning with this principle, you'll see the output you get is the one that is expected.
Here is a simplified view on the sequence of operations. It depicts the callstack at the left, the current action being performed, the state of all relevant promises (F=Fulfilled, P=pending), and the jobs that are in the promise job queue (microtask queue):



Call stack
Action
p0
p1
p2
p3
Promise job queue




Script
f1()







Script>f1
log('A')







Script>f1
f3()







Script>f1>f3
f2()







Script>f1>f3>f2
r()







Script>f1>f3>f2
p0 = resolve(...)
F






Script>f1>f3>f2
return p0
F






Script>f1>f3
p2 = ...
F

P!

fulfill(p2)


Script>f1>f3
await p2
F

P

fulfill(p2)


Script>f1
p3 = ...
F

P
P
fulfill(p2)


Script>f1
log('C')
F

P
P
fulfill(p2)


Script>f1
return
F

P
P
fulfill(p2)


Script
p1 = ...
F
F
P
P
fulfill(p2)


Script
await p1
F
F
P
P
fulfill(p2) resume script



Check queues
F
F
P
P
fulfill(p2) resume script


fullfill(p2)
fullfill(p2)
F
F
F
P
resume script resume f3



Check queues
F
F
F
P
resume script resume f3


Script-resumed
log('D')
F
F
F
P
resume f3



Check queues
F
F
F
P
resume f3


f3-resumed
log('B')
F
F
F
P



f3-resumed
return
F
F
F
F





This is a tricky exercise that explores concepts like the task queue, microtask queue, and how the event loop works.
When the program runs, await funcOne will be called (and placed inside the microtask queue), and it will immediately output "A" because this is a synchronous operation. Next, the IIFE will execute. At the await funcTwo() line, funcTwo runs and completes immediately. However, the .then callback of the promise is not executed right away. Instead, it is placed in the microtask queue.
The program will then move on from the IIFE without waiting (because don't have any await to hold it) for its result to complete and proceed to the next synchronous task, which is logging "C." At this point, the execution of funcOne finishes, and the program continues after await funcOne();, logging "Done." because is the next synchronous operation.
Once all the synchronous tasks are finished, the event loop will process the microtask queue. This is when "B" will be logged.
In this link, you can have a more detail explanation about those three concepts.

'logging "Done." because is the next synchronous operation.': "Done" is not logged synchronously with the previous code. Code that follows below an await is always executed asynchronously, via a queued promise job.

@trincot, sure, thanks for the clarification and the great explanation in your answer
